# Install MongoDB on Manjaro

Tags: mongodb, archlinux, manjaro

I'm facing difficulties installing the MongoDB community server on Manjaro Linux.

There isn't official documentation on how to install it on Arch-based systems and Pacman can't find it in the AUR repos.

Has anyone ever tried to install it?

Comment: Pacman doesn't search in AUR, and `pamac` (the other package manager) searches only with `pamac search -a mongodb` - and finds something.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Here is what I did to install.

As the package is [not available](https://lists.archlinux.org/pipermail/arch-dev-public/2019-January/029430.html) in the official Arch repositories and can't be installed using `pacman`, you need to follow a few steps to install it.

First, you need to get the URL for the repo of prebuilt binaries from AUR. It can be [found here](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/mongodb-bin/) and by the time of writing this it was https://aur.archlinux.org/mongodb-bin.git

Simply clone the repo in your home directory or anywhere else. Do `git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/mongodb-bin.git`, then head to the cloned directory, `cd mongodb-bin`.

Now, all you need to do is to run `makepkg -si` command to make the package. the `-s` flag will handle the dependencies for you and the `-i` flag will install the package.

After `makepkg` finishes its execution, don't forget to start `mongodb.service`. Run `systemctl start mongodb` and if needed enable it with `systemctl enable mongodb`.

Type `mongo` in the terminal and if the Mongo Shell runs you are all set.

---

Later edit (8.2.2021): This package is now available in AUR.

Comment: I've tested the solution on Manjaro Linux. Works fine. Thank you.

Comment: This works well even just now. However, would this be update alongside all other packages during system updates?

Comment: @Touchstone you can update this kind of packages using AUR package tool like yay, yay uses similar syntax to pacman, to update official and non-official packages you can use: yay -Syua

Comment: If it's on AUR, you can search for it `pamac search -a mongodb` and then install it with `pamac build mongodb`.

Comment: @TomaszGandor when I run `pamac build mongodb` it just builds forever. I left it running for an hour and came back and still wasn't done. It looks like it's stuck in a dep check loop. Any idea how to work around that?

Comment: @KylerJohnson, yes, try `pamac build mongodb-bin` ;)

Comment: And by that manner, you can install also MongoDB Compass, thanks bro!

Comment: @ZavenZareyan my pleasure :)

Comment: Perfect in Manjaro Linux! thanks bro!

Answer (score 12):

It is available in AUR, so you can view it with pamac with -a flag,
eg.

```sh
  pamac search -a mongodb-bin
  pamac info -a mongodb-bin
```

And, then build and install with (this can be done after manually cloning too) -

```sh
  pamac build mongodb-bin
```

Note that there's also a package named `mongodb`, but `mongodb-bin` is a newer release (you can check the version numbers by search or info arguments)

Answer (score 6):

I've been using mongodb `via docker` for a couple of years.
In my experience, **it's easier** than installing the regular way. (assuming you already have docker installed)

## 1. Ensure you have docker installed

If you don't already have it, you can install via pacman/pamac, because it's in the official Arch/Manjaro package repositories. The easiest way is to run the following command:

```
sudo pacman -S docker
```

## 2. Run a single docker command

```
sudo docker run -d -p 27017:27017 -v ~/mongodb_data:/data/db mongo
```

This command will run mongodb on a `port 27017`, and place its data files into a folder `~/mongodb_data`.
If you're running this command for the first time, it will also download all the required files.

Now you're successfully running a local instance of mongodb, and you can connect it with your favorite db management tool or from your code.

Comment: nice i like this. but in this case i'd need to install the mongodbshell separately?

Comment: to get a shell, use --it

`docker exec -it mongodb bash`

Comment: you have to provide a name like this `sudo docker run -d -p 27017:27017 -v ~/mongodb_data:/data/db --name MyMongo mongo:latest` then run `docker exec -it MyMongo bash`